# Interacting with iFrame elements before its hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, wistia

I am trying to figure out how to capture the hide event (display:none;) inside an iframe. I have three iframes, and only one at a time is visible, the other two iFrames are hidden. I am using jQuery show(), hide() methods to hide and show different iframes :

```
$('#currentFrame').hide();
$('#newIframe').show();
```

I have embedded wistia videos inside these iframes and when one iframe is switched to another I want to pause the current video. hence I want to capture the hide event.

Inside the iFrame I tried this but it doesn't get triggered

`$(document).blur( function () {
    var video = Wistia.api("video1");
    video.pause();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following example, it uses the postMessage function

https://robertnyman.com/html5/postMessage/postMessage.html

Comment: I actually want to capture the event from within the iframe window.

Comment: I got your point - I before calling the hide method on the iframe I am invoking postMessage and pause on message.